# PHP Session data gone after changing from subdomain to domain

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I have the issue that when I set a session on `subdomain.domain.com` it is empty on `domain.com`
I tried already everything I could find on Google and Stackoverflow nothing worked.
Both are on HTTPs, the weird thing is if I check the session ID on the `domain.com` it is the same, but the `$_SESSION` variable is just empty.
If I check the cookies in the browser everything looks fine, it is also displayed as `.domain.com` so it should cover all subdomains + domain

[image]

This is my code:

```
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
$domain = ".domain.com";

ini_set('session.cookie_domain', $domain);

session_name("domain_session");
session_set_cookie_params(0, $cookieParams["path"], $domain, true, true);
```

Any my settings:

```
@ini_set("suhosin.session.encrypt", "On");
@ini_set("suhosin.session.cryptraddr", "On");
@ini_set("suhosin.session.cryptua", "Off");
```

Any ideas what else I can do?

Comment: You are using suhosin there, so other options like `suhosin.session.cryptdocroot` could also have an influence on this. (If this flag was true, and the document root for your domain and subdomain where set to different directories, this should make the session decryption fail. Many of the same options exists also exist for encryption of the cookie, but since you said you got the same session ID, I would assume cookie encryption is not in play, or not the issue here.)

Comment: @CBroe I'm not using Suhosin, I don't even know what this is. But I found the issue, it was because I called the ajax request which creates a session through the domain and not the subdomain. IDK how this is connected to the session, but it fixed it.

Comment: Then why are you trying to _set_ configuration options that would affect suhosin's behavior ...?!?

Comment: @CBroe I found them in a different SO post as a fix for the same issue and thought it is default option. But for sure I can remove them now.